# site freaking out

Tags: wordpress

please visit http://bigginsroofing.com

notice how the site never loads, and the page keeps reloading, nothing the url in the address bar:

```
http://www1.bigginsroofing.com/?framerequest=1&refurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww1.bigginsroofing.com%2F%3Fframerequest%3D1%26refurl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww1.bigginsroofing.com%252F%253Fframerequest%253D1%2526refurl%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww1.bigginsroofing.com%25252F%25253Fframerequest%25253D1%252526refurl%25253Dhttp%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Fwww1.bigginsroofing.com%2525252F%2525253Fframerequest%2525253D1%25252526refurl%2525253D
```

as this is a wordpress site, interestingly i have no problems visiting the admin section.

i have n idea what could be causing this, and where i could look to troubleshoot.

no plugins enabled, and still occurs. dns seems fine, and htaccess also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

This turned out to be another one of the fake jQuery spam backlinks. Basically some code would be inserted in your site's HTML pretending that they are loading jQuery. [Here](http://www.robgonda.com/2012/07/12/wordpress-hacked-spam-backlinks/) you can see a bit more details, or you can do a search on your own as well.

---

This is caused by JS redirection. I guess that the offending code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">StaticRequestInfo={Referer:document.referrer};function EscapeBrowserFrame(){try{if(window.top.location==window.self.location){}...
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">InitiateFrameRequest();</script>
```

Also your HTML is a mess - you have two `<html>` tags, which is completely wrong. Look in your theme directory's `header.php` file - this is where you should be able to fix the `HTML` error. The JS code could be there as well.

Comment: thanks. i couldn't locate either of the issues in the theme header. here's the header.php - http://pastebin.com/FZtWWEU6

Comment: i've searched the entire root for the above code. perhaps it's obfuscated..

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? The code is most-likely hooked to the `wp_head()` function. Now it seems that instead of the previous refresh code, you have one that redirects to a google's domainparking service :/

Comment: That's pretty weird - can you look in your functions.php to see if you can find the abusing code? You can also try commenting-out the `wp_head()` call like so - `// wp_head()` and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: Cool, you no longer have the redirection - did you find the problem or you just commented-out the the `wp_head()` call?

Comment: i could not find any errors... i just reloaded all theme files from a backup, however now there are other issues. i wish i could revert to the files i had before, but clearly there is some malicious code..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19873/discussion-between-nikola-ivanov-nikolov-and-vulgarbulgar)